# As per the beginner tutorial 1, when i try this command (export | grep) in terminal I am getting the following in my terminal

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
siva@siva-Inspiron-N5110:~$ export | grep ROSdeclare -x ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=""
declare -x ROS_DISTRO="hydro"
declare -x ROS_ETC_DIR="/opt/ros/hydro/etc/ros"
declare -x ROS_MASTER_URI="http://localhost:11311"
declare -x ROS_PACKAGE_PATH="/opt/ros/hydro/share:/opt/ros/hydro/stacks"
declare -x ROS_ROOT="/opt/ros/hydro/share/ros"
siva@siva-Inspiron-N5110:~$
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203313/as-per-the-beginner-tutorial-1,-when-i-try-this-command-(export-%7C-grep)-in-terminal-i--am-getting-the-following-in-my-terminal.-kindly-give-me-a-solution/) by [SIVA](https://answers.ros.org/users/21663/siva/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-02-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [corb](https://answers.ros.org/users/20674/corb/) on 2015-02-17**:
It's not clear what your question is. What do you need a solution to?

**Comment by [SIVA](https://answers.ros.org/users/21663/siva/) on 2015-02-18**:
declare -x ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=""
declare -x ROS_DISTRO="hydro"
declare -x ROS_ETC_DIR="/opt/ros/hydro/etc/ros"
When i execute export | grep i get the above statements displayed. Does this represent that all these paths are set or it is an error??

Does these

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There doesn't seem to be an error there that I can see.

Based on your comment, note that what you're seeing aren't necessarily *paths*. The capitalized items are *environment variables*, some of whose values are set to paths (e.g., `ROS_ROOT` is set to `/opt/ros/hydro/share/ros`), some set to other things (e.g., `ROS_DISTRO` is set to the string `hydro` and `ROS_MASTER_URI` is set to the URL `http://localhost:11311`).

All of `export`, `grep`, and `|` (called *pipe*) are command-line commands; to learn more, read the man pages (either google the terms or, from the command line, use the `man` command).

---

Originally posted by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) with karma: 1470 on 2015-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SIVA](https://answers.ros.org/users/21663/siva/) on 2015-02-18**:
Ya i got it. thanks a lot for the reply.